# Have users add content to a streaming video?

Tags: flv, flash-html-interaction

Let's say I have a flash video streaming website, what are some ways in which users could add comments, links, effectively mark up a video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just allow them to add comments and links using the videos unique id and store this info in your database? Unless you mean editing the video itself.

You could use flash to read comments from an xml file then display it on top of the video. PLease elaborate on how you want these comments displayed.

Edit: If your looking to do it how youtube does it create a swf in flash that can read from an xml file (where the xml file takes the videos unique id to query the datbase to retrieve the comments).. the comments would then be displayed on top of the video as labels. Please reference actionscript 2 or 3 depending on what version of flash you're using.

Comment: I think he means like youtube does it. Adding captions.

Comment: AS3 I guess.  Similar effect to what youtube does with annotations.